# ORDER BY RAND EN GROUP BY CON JOIN

Tags: sql, random, group-by

comparto las siguientes líneas conteniendo las instrucciones para que me devuelva un sólo registro desde la extracción de datos de MySQL, al que le he añadido un link para modificar dicho registro, volviendo luego a la misma página tras haberse modificado el registro. Esto funcionaría fantástico si pudiera ordenar aleatoriamente (By RAND) la consulta antes de imprimir un registro, pero me tira error.
Desde ya, muchas gracias:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT *, OPCION1, count(OPCION1) CANTIDAD 
FROM apa_seminarios_inscripciones
INNER JOIN apa_roster_fuente
    ON apa_seminarios_inscripciones.CODIGOPERSONAAPA= apa_roster_fuente.CODIGOPERSONAAPA
INNER JOIN apa_seminarios_fuente 
    ON apa_seminarios_inscripciones.OPCION1=apa_seminarios_fuente.SEMINARIO
WHERE OPCION1 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY OPCION1 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 15




");
if ($row = mysql_num_rows($result))
{
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
echo ""  .$row['CANTIDAD']. " inscriptos en este seminario<br>";
echo ""  .$row['OPCION1']. "<br>";
echo ""  .$row['TITULO']. " - ";
echo "Profesor: ".$row['PROFESOR']."<br>";
echo "<strong>Mínimo : </strong>".$row['MINIMO']." - ";
echo "<strong>Máximo: </strong>".$row['MAXIMO']." - <br>";
echo "".$row['NOMBREX']." ";
echo "".$row['APELLIDOX']."<br> ";
echo '<font color="red"><a target=_self href="paso1sorteo.php?ID='.$row['ID'].'"> ACTUALIZAR</a></font><br><br>';
}
}
else                
{                   
echo '<strong></strong>';               
}           
mysql_free_result($result);             
?>
```

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: Hola. Soy neófito en esto. Sucede  que logro el orden RAND, pero no anda el count. Creo que entonces debería pedir ayuda en relación al count, ya que no me devuelve la sumatoria de inscriptos (en el campo OPCION1)

SELECT *, OPCION1, count(OPCION1) CANTIDAD 
FROM (select *, ID AS IDasf2 from apa_seminarios_inscripciones order by rand()) as T
INNER JOIN apa_roster_fuente
  ON T.CODIGOPERSONAAPA= apa_roster_fuente.CODIGOPERSONAAPA
INNER JOIN apa_seminarios_fuente 
  ON T.OPCION1=apa_seminarios_fuente.SEMINARIO
WHERE OPCION1 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY OPCION1 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 15
");

Answer (score 2):

Perdón, ya encontré el error y quiero cerrar esta pregunta. Les dejo igual el query que me anda, por el cual selecciono grupos de inscripciones a seminarios distintos agrupados por seminarios, devolviéndome un sólo registro random (para confirmar exclusiones mediane un link UPDATE), y contando la cantidad total de inscriptos por seminario.

```
SELECT *, OPCIONSEMINARIO1, count(OPCIONOPCIONSEMINARIO) CANTIDAD 
FROM (select *, ID AS IDasf2 from seminarios_inscripciones order by rand()) as T
INNER JOIN roster_fuente
    ON T.CODIGOPERSONAAPA= apa_roster_fuente.CODIGOPERSONAAPA
INNER JOIN seminarios_fuente 
    ON T.OPCIONOPCIONSEMINARIO=_seminarios_fuente.SEMINARIO
WHERE OPCIONOPCIONSEMINARIO IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY OPCIONOPCIONSEMINARIO 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 15
");
```

Comment: acuérdate que si esta respuesta soluciona el problema, la puedes marcar como aceptada